# The mystery flag

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, visual, sequence, flags

Part two - [**The mystery flag - twisted**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32222/the-mystery-flag-twisted)

---

Based on these flags:

[image]

*(Count the sun in the Argentina flag as yellow)*

> **Which country does this flag belong to?**

[image]

**Please explain why**

<sub>EDIT: I added a black background to clarify what is flag and what is background. Don't count the black as a colour when solving.</sub>

Comment: Is it relevant that the [flag of Pakistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Pakistan) has a field of white on the left side? (you can't actually tell it's there the way the first image is put together)

Comment: The Argentinian flag has four colours, white, sky blue, and gold and brown in the sun.

Comment: @PeteKirkham for the sake of this say the sun is yellow

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Answer :

> **AFG HANISTAN**

Reasoning

> The country names are split in two parts: the first part having the same number of letters as colors in the flag.
> So:
> A - White
> G - Yellow
> R - Blue
> F - Red
> P - Green.
> The shown flag is White - Red - Yellow so AFG. Only country that starts with those letters is Afghanistan.

Comment: Correct! Well thought out

Comment: [Nuh uh!](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Flag_of_Afghanistan.svg/2000px-Flag_of_Afghanistan.svg.png)

Comment: @SendersReagent - the point is that this would be the flag if you followed the rules about country names and colours

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 I know, there is zero joking allowed on Planet Stack Exchange. I apologize.