# The mystery flag - twisted

Tags: pattern, visual, flags

The original [**Mystery flag**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31911/the-mystery-flag)

And now a twisted version...

Based on these flags:[image: Flags]

(All the reds should be taken as the same colour)

> **Which country does this flag belong to?**

[image]

Hint:

> There is a clue in the question

Comment: Name of the countries to which these flags belongs to respectively are: Vietnam, Turkey, Yemen, Morocco

Comment: @LuxxMiner, no it doesn't

Comment: @manshu, unlike the previous question, more info is needed here, the hint may help

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I could answer that the flag was that of Germany because it was one of the German flag ideas post-WWII.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> These given four flags are of the countries Vietnam, Turkey, Yemen, Morocco respectively.
>
>  Now the capitals of these countries are Hanoi, Ankara, Sana, Rabat.

By the same logic as the linked question we can say

> The capitals names are split in two parts: the first part having the same number of letters as colors in the flag.
>  So:
>  A - Red
>  H - Yellow
>  R - Green
>  N - White
>  S - Black.
>  
>  The flag shown is Red, Black, Yellow. So ASH. Only capital that starts with those letters is Ashgabat, which is the capital of **Turkmenistan**

Or maybe it's just a flag of Belgium with colors twisted. Who knows? ;-)

Comment: Also the airport code for Nashua, NH

Comment: @SMSvonderTann True. But I guessed that Beastly Gerbil was expecting an answer in the terms of capital. :)

Comment: @manshu quite right, I was :P well done

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I am still wondering about the clue in the question. What was it?

Comment: @manshu, the clue was written in **capitals**. But tenuous